# Use of "former" with "before" superfluous?

Tags: usage

In the following sentence I think the use of the word **former** is superfluous.

> Mr. Malik was the **former** Governor of Bihar **before** he was shifted to Jammu and Kashmir. He was also given the additional charge of Odisha for a brief period in 2018.

[***Link***](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/girish-chandra-murmu-appointed-lt-governor-of-jammu-kashmir-satya-pal-malik-moved-to-goa/article29800804.ece)

Because **former** and **before** used in the sentence mean the same thing.

Comment: Yep, not needed.

Comment: There is no question in your post, but I agree with your statement.

Answer (score 1):

The word **former** is actually *wrong* here, not superfluous.

Here is the sequence of events:

1. 2017–2018: Mr. Malik was the Governor of Bihar.
2. 2018–today: Mr. Malik was the Governor of Jammu and Kashmir.
3. Today: Mr. Malik became the Governor of Goa.

The word **former** is wrong because it indicates that Mr. Malik had already ceased being the Governor of Bihar ("the former Governor") at the time when he was shifted to Jammu and Kashmir.

However, superfluous redundancy is not always bad. Redundancy can be good. In this case, it helps to add *something* to help the reader sort out this sequence of three governorships (and maybe a fourth in Odisha; [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_governors_of_Odisha) seems complicated). Here is a good way to add this redundancy:

> Mr. Malik was **formerly** the Governor of Bihar before he was shifted to Jammu and Kashmir.

This part of the news story provides background for the main story. The word **formerly** is a conventional way to describe offices previously held by someone when giving background about them.

Comment: Thanks to [TypeIA](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/82065/typeia) for correcting a big mistake in a previous version of this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily, I'd expect *Mr. Malik **is** the former Governor of Bihar*. But that clashes with the adverbial clause ***before he was*** [moved elsewhere], since ***at that time*** (before being moved), he was the ***incumbent*** Governor, not a ***former*** holder of the office.

It's quite possible the writer originally used ***is + former*** before deciding to add that conflicting adverbial clause, and subsequent "proof-reading" was less than perfect.

But it's not the kind of thing native speakers would particularly notice unless they were *looking* for errors (calling attention to it smacks of pedantic "nit-picking"). My advice would be to treat this as a *very* minor "lapse" (don't copy it, but don't get worked up about it either).